# Missing StackTrace Information

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

I seem to be missing some information from my stack trace, here is what i'm getting:

```
at Foo.Bar(DataTable table) in D:\Foo\Bar\authoring\App_Code\FooBar.vb:line 87
```

Where is the rest of the stack trace infomation?

EDIT:

Custom errors in the Web.Config is set to off, i'm handling the error where it's caught like this:

```
 Catch ex As Exception
     Respose.Write(ex.StackTrace)
 End Try
```

The Stack Trace is still getting truncated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure customErrors is set to "RemoteOnly" or "Off" in your web.config to disable friendly errors.

Or possibly stack trace getting reset? (Although if this was the case you still should see something)

Will reset your stack trace.

```
catch(Exception ex) 
{
   throw ex; 
}
```

Will NOT reset your stack trace.

```
catch(Exception ex) 
{
   throw; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

*[ex.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx)* gets the current stack. The stacktrace starts
where the exception was thrown(error happens) and ends at the current stack frame where the exception is caught. So it is reversing the call stack. Since you are writing out stacktrace as soon as it happens it doesn't get a chance to go any further up the callstack.

Depending on what you are doing you can try a few things.

```
//To just see the stackTrace
Catch ex As Exception
     Throw
 End Try
```

[Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx) - Gets current stack trace information

```
//If you are trying to log the stacktrace 
Catch ex As Exception
     Respose.Write(Environment.StackTrace)
     Respose.Write(ex.StackTrace)
 End Try

//If is hiding then try - hiding as in throw ex vs just throw
Catch ex As Exception
     //careful innerException can be null
     //so need to check before using it
     Respose.Write(ex.InnerException)
 End Try
```

One of those methods should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, see my edits for more information. Any help you can give me is much appreciated.